# How to dynamically set pool size for AveragePooling2D layer/ How to pass external value to an sequential layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Trying to understand [listwise documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/listwise_ranking)

while trying to replicate by mixing [deep model](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/deep_recommenders) to listwise I am stuck at point where I am not able to set the pool size inside the sequential layer in an dynamic manner. For example consider below code

```
!pip install -q tensorflow-recommenders
!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow-datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow-ranking
import pprint

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_ranking as tfr
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
from typing import Dict, Text
import os
import tempfile
import datetime
ratings = tfds.load("movielens/100k-ratings", split="train")
movies = tfds.load("movielens/100k-movies", split="train")

ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {
    "movie_title": x["movie_title"],
    "user_id": x["user_id"],
    "user_rating": x["user_rating"],
    # "timestamp": x["timestamp"],
})
movies = movies.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])

unique_movie_titles = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(movies.batch(1000))))
unique_user_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(ratings.batch(1_000).map(
    lambda x: x["user_id"]))))


class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000_00

    self.title_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens)

    self.title_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      # tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      self.title_vectorizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, 32, mask_zero=True),
      tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1,4),strides=1,    padding='valid',),
    ])
    self.title_vectorizer.adapt(movies)

  def call(self, titles):
    return self.title_text_embedding(titles)
```

After we create movie model lets try to test it before we can use it on proper movie data

below is the test code

```
test_movie_titles = [["M*A*S*H (1970)", "Dances with Wolves (1990)", "Speed (1994)","Dances with Wolves (1990)", "Speed (1994)"]]
md = MovieModel()
test_ratings = md(tf.constant(tf.reshape(test_movie_titles,[1,5,1])) )  
test_ratings
```

This now works perfect and I will get an output as below

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5, 1, 32), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ 0.00778975, -0.00899004,  0.02926993, -0.00527342,
           0.00706512,  0.02012717,  0.03438753,  0.01971687,
          -0.00543808, -0.00754605, -0.02241766,  0.00045748,
          -0.00785657, -0.00291913,  0.00670988,  0.01176082,
          -0.02052191, -0.00751739, -0.01433057,  0.008
-----
----
```

Now if you notice in the code above I have hardcoded the pool_size as 1,4 ( `tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1,4),strides=1,    padding='valid',),`) because the test sample I had used above only have maximum 4 words, so the vectorization will produce vector of size 4, now problem is how to I ensure the right pool size when I pass the whole dataset (movies) to the model. How can I pass such external value (pool_size) to an sequential layer from outside?

The above code was run on google colab using tensorflow version 2.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000_00

    self.title_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens)

    self.title_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      # tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      self.title_vectorizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, 32, mask_zero=True),
    ])
    self.title_vectorizer.adapt(movies)

  def call(self, titles, pool_size):
    avg_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=pool_size,strides=1,padding='valid',)
    return avg_layer(self.title_text_embedding(titles))
```

```
test_movie_titles = [["M*A*S*H (1970)", "Dances with Wolves (1990)", "Speed (1994)","Dances with Wolves (1990)", "Speed (1994)"]]
md = MovieModel()
test_ratings = md(tf.constant(tf.reshape(test_movie_titles,[1,5,1])),  pool_size = (1, 4))  
test_ratings
```